# Enable again Shellcheck in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, shellcheck

After an update of PhpStorm (MacOS) to the new release and some troubles which led me to remove all PhpStorm app instances and reinstall the latest release and then copying the plugins back to the app folder in "~/Library/Application Support" I was asked again to enable Shellcheck for a shell script I was working on. For that particular file I didn't need the Shellcheck, so I've disabled it. But then Shellcheck didn't work for all scripts and I couldn't find any option in the PhpStorm settings to enable it again. The only option I've found was already checked:

[image]

So how can I enable it again?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found by accident the solution. In the subsetting "Shellcheck" I had some placeholder text (don't remember exact phrase) instead of the path to the Shellcheck script. Once I've removed the text, I've got a warning about missing Shellcheck and an action link to download it. [image]

After clicking on it, the correct path was filled automatically and the Shellcheck started to work again. The path was then:

```
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/plugins/Shell Script/shellcheck
```

Answer (score 0):

The shellcheck script in the PHPStorm Shell Script plugin directory may be broken/corrupted during a PHPStorm (or plugin) update.

If shellcheck isn't working, consider changing this setting to a separate, OS-installed Shellcheck (/usr/bin/shellcheck, etc.) to test it out (or fixes the issue outright). See [the README on Github](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck?tab=readme-ov-file#shellcheck---a-shell-script-static-analysis-tool) for a list of available installation options.